# Windows 7 lan, shared folder transmission slow

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've already disabled autotuning, Large Send Offload, Remote Differential Compression. 
I've also disabled ipv6, but it still transferring at 200-500 kbps.

It's a wireless home connection, with four pc's (Windows 7 64 bits), the wireless network card is a TP Link 300mbps.

Any ideas on how to improve the lan transfer speed?

Comment: Did you check the Wi-Fi signal strength? What are the technical specifications? What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the network card, and what's the current driver version?  This article might be of interest: [Simple change in settings pumps up Win7 networks](http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/simple-change-in-settings-pumps-up-win7-networks/)

Comment: The wi-fi signal is good, the PCI info is: Wireless N PCI Adapter TL-WN851ND, and the driver is not updated. Thank you very much for the tips and the link! I'll update the driver, change some configurations and see how it goes!